# How to sum 2-d array in JS with strings and numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

is there any elegant solution to make it

```
[ [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ], [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ] ]
```

looking like it?

```
[ [ 'QUARTER', 0.50 ] ]
```

Comment: I would suggest the better data structure would be to use `Map` in JS, instead of the array for this use case.

Comment: Mixed-type arrays are generally a design flaw, but beyond that, the expected behavior is unclear and no attempt was shown. What result do you expect if your array is `[ [ 'NICKEL', 0.05 ], [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ] ]`?

Comment: @ggorlen `[ [ 'NICKEL', 0.05 ], [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ] , [ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ]]`
the finnal version should look like `[ [ 'NICKEL', 0.05 ],[ 'QUARTER', 0.50 ]]`

Answer (score 2):

Do it with with reduce...

```js
let array = [[ 'QUARTER', 0.25 ], [ 'DIME', 0.20 ], [ 'QUARTER', 0.75 ], [ 'DIME', 0.10 ] ];

let reduced = array.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const coin = el[0], value = el[1];
  acc[coin] ? acc[coin] += value : acc[coin] = value
  return acc
}, {})

// round real valued sums to currency accuracy
reduced = Object.entries(reduced).map(a => [a[0], a[1].toFixed(2)])
console.log(reduced)
```